# Access to raw signal from microphone plug

Tags: c, signal-processing, hardware

I need to gain access to stream of raw signal from my microphone plug in my laptop. Since my experience in writing code to directly interact with hardware is next to none I would welcome any possible reference to start with.

I'm working on Linux - Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Start with the platform: Windows? Linux? A [freestanding](http://wiki.osdev.org/C_Library#Freestanding_and_Hosted) program?

Comment: How “raw” do you need your access? Do you just want the unfiltered PCM samples from the microphone at a specified sampling rate or is there anything more?

Comment: @FUZxxl Ideally I would have readings of electric current sampled on a given rate - is it feasible?

Comment: @data: It is certainly possible but it is a bit peculiar. Can you elaborate a little on what you are trying to achieve and why you want to the measure current as opposed to the voltage which would traditionally be sampled?

Comment: You can use [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)

Answer (score 4):

> Ideally I would have readings of electric current sampled on a given rate

Congratulations, that **is** what sound cards do (usually, they sample voltage, but with a fixed resistance, that's equivalent to current).

You have to realize a few things:

- When sampling any signal, you must limit the bandwidth of your signal; [Nyquist's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) mathematically describes that. In your real sampling case, that limit is half the sampling rate. Most sound cards hence have exactly one analog low pass filter that filters out anything above the audible rate. Don't expect the input to be very well-represented above ca. 11kHz.
- Sound cards are designed to be AC-coupled to their inputs; that means that there is a capacitor between your microphone plug and your Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC). Which means that only signal with a frequency significantly higher than 0Hz (how much depends on the sound card, really) reaches the ADC, and DC will not.

  - you can get cheap USB sound "cards" where you could bridge that capacitor. But I've actually contacted a manufacturer of sound card ICs about that very topic, and they can make no guarantees regarding DC accuracy or crosstalk.
- You have to realize that if your signal matches the "half-sampling rate" criterion mentioned above for the resampled rate, too, then the digital filters used in the resampler should not really distort it. So, go for the easiest way you can get audio signal into your application.

My usual paragraph: Ceterum censeo GNU Radium esse proliferandem. Hence, have a look at what GNU Radio's "Audio Source" can do for you. GNU Radio is a complete Framework to build signal processing [flow graphs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnuradio/gr-tutorial/master/examples/tutorial2/images/tutorial_two_7.png) having a lot of useful processing blocks. Have a glimpse at the [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials), especially the [introduction](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorial_Introduction), which gives a little more illustration to the bullet points above. Maybe you can see whether it'd a good fit to your problem. If you want to try without any hassle, use the [GNU Radio Live DVD/USB image](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GNURadioLiveDVD).

Other than that, under Linux the usual system sound API is called "ALSA", and really isn't impossible to work with, if you've worked with similar C APIs before -- that being said, it's not beautiful. If you already use a framework that has Multimedia capabilities (e.g. SDL), you might want to stick with that.